# Rails 3.2 layout: "except" not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a Root controller and I want to authenticate the user, so I added the authentication codes in the layout for Root. I wanted to exclude the index and the login page from the layout, so I added:

```
layout 'roots', :except =>  ['index', 'login']
```

in my RootsController. However, when I open the index and login page, the layout still appears. I tried to use :only to include all the pages I wanted to include, but again, the layout was applied to all pages.

I am really confused. Thanks!

Comment: The problem was solved when I added render :layout => false in my index and login method. But I still don't understand why my codes above did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work. Have you tried passing `layout` option in `format.html` block?

For example:

`format.html { :layout => 'roots' }`

Comment: It is ok for me to add this code into each individual page except index and login, but that would be so tedious and not DRY. What I really want to do is to exclude the index and login page from using the layout, and I just don't know why my codes do not work..

Comment: @Lee7355512727: Yeah you are right that adding `layout` to each method will not be a DRY[ish] way of doing things. Can you confirm that your code works if you add `:layout` in `format.html`? If yes then it is bit ambiguous that why it is not working in Rails standard way.